# io_service::run() never returns

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

**UPDATE_2**
I ended up using

```
if (socket.available())
```

If there is data on the socket, I read it and if not, I skip.

**UPDATED**
I have a problem. io_service::run() never returns in the following code snippet:

The client side:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void handler(
    const boost::system::error_code &error,
    size_t bytes_transferred
)
{
    cout << "Handler called" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    //establishing connection
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "17073");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
    //connection established

    boost::array<char, 128> buf;
    socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), boost::bind(handler, _1, _2));

    //async_read_some returns

    io_service.run();       //I suppose that handler_for_async_response is called if:
                            //1) EOF was read (no data read twice) by async_read_some
                            //2) something was in fact read
                            //is this right?

    //execution does not get here

    return 0;
}
```

The server side(only accepts the connection and hangs there doing nothing):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    //establishing connection
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::socket             socket(io_service);
    tcp::acceptor           acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 17073));

    acceptor.accept(socket);

    std::cout << "connection has been established!" << std::endl;
    //connection established

    while (true)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is see if there is any data on the socket. If yes - then read it, if no - then move on.

PS I am planning to both read from the socket and write to it.

Anyway, I am new to boost::asio and I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** In response to updated question with code:

---

Your client is waiting for 128 bytes or EOF. None of these come, because the server doesn't send anything (yet doesn't close the connection).

Either change

1. the client, e.g.

   - Don't wait for actual data to arrive

     ```
     boost::array<char, 0> buf;
     ```
   - Or make it `socket.cancel()` after a `deadline_timer` (or so.
2. the server, e.g. replace the infinite loop with a true socket write

Here's a sample

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34630d4fdaa8c09f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;

#ifdef SERVER
    int main()
    {
        //establishing connection
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::socket             socket(io_service);
        tcp::acceptor           acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 17073));

        acceptor.accept(socket);

        std::cout << "connection has been established!" << std::endl;
        //connection established

        socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(std::string("Hello world\n")));
    }
#else
    void handler(
        boost::array<char, 128> const& buf,
        const boost::system::error_code &error,
        size_t bytes_transferred
    )
    {
        cout << "Handler called (" << error.message() << "): "  << endl;
        cout.write(buf.data(), bytes_transferred);
    }

    int main()
    {
        //establishing connection
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "17073");
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
        //connection established

        boost::array<char, 128> buf;
        socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), boost::bind(handler, boost::ref(buf), _1, _2));

        //async_read_some returns

        io_service.run();       //I suppose that handler_for_async_response is called if:
                                //1) EOF was read (no data read twice) by async_read_some
                                //2) something was in fact read
                                //is this right?

        //execution does not get here

        return 0;
    }
#endif
```

Prints:

```
//(server)
connection has been established!
//(client)
Handler called (Success):
```

### Hello world

You have to make up your mind about synchronous or asynchronous programming.

In this case, I'd think you're probably looking for `tcp::istream` really.

---

Run returns when it runs out of tasks:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html

> The `run()` function blocks until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched, or until the `io_service` has been stopped.
>
> Multiple threads may call the `run()` function to set up a pool of threads from which the `io_service` may execute handlers. All threads that are waiting in the pool are equivalent and the `io_service` may choose any one of them to invoke a handler.
>
> A normal exit from the `run()` function implies that the `io_service` object is stopped (the stopped() function returns true). Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately unless there is a prior call to `reset()`.

So you have other work pending on the service (io_service::work?). Check that. Make your code a SSCCE and we would be able to see more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just edited the question following your advice :) I will take a look at tcp::istream

Comment: @sehe thanks for making it clear why the function loops. I decided to do things synchronously though and ended up using socket.available().